# Is $fetched some implicit variable in Perl

Tags: perl, variables, dbi

I'm trying to analyze a CGI file written in Perl. I know that a variable declared in file A that uses/requires file B is available in file B as long as it's global. But please take a look at this piece of code:

```perl
sub makeoper {
%attr = (
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 0
);

$dbh=DBI->connect($configs{db_source},$configs{db_user},$configs{db_passw},\%attr) or die "Can not connect to database: $DBI::errstr!\n";
 if ($fetched{submit} eq 'start' and !$fetched{savefr} )
  {$fetched{savefr}=&get_time_fromdb;
   $fetched{saveto}='';
   system "mv pool/*.txt pool/arc/";
  }
 #some more else ifs
 $dbh->disconnect or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
}
```

Where is this `$fetched` variable taken from? The `$configs` avriable, for instance, comes from a config file. I've searched all the files in the directory there's no `$fetched`anywhere. Is it some kind of implicit variable when fetching data? If not, then where else should I look?

Just in case, I'm posting the whole code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;

#$ENV { "ORACLE_HOME" } = "/d01/conf/oracle/product/924";

sub printPage(){
&parse_form || exit;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
&makeoper;
#&makeoper;
print "<html><head></head>
<body>
<h3>$configs{servicename}</h3>
<form action='$ENV{REQUEST_URI}' method='post'>
<table align='center' width='96%' border='1'>
<tr>
<td width='50%' align='left' valign='top'>
Online-cutting <br><br>
<input type=hidden name='savefr' value='$fetched{savefr}'>$fetched{savefr}
 - 
<input type=hidden name='saveto' value='$fetched{saveto}'>$fetched{saveto}
<br>
<input type=submit name='submit' value='start'>
<input type=submit name='submit' value='cut'>
<input type=submit name='submit' value='stop'>
</td>
<td align='left' valign='top' bgcolor='\#eeeeee'>
Take history <br>
<small>
 (times in format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS<br>
                or YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI<br>
                or YYYY-MM-DD )<br>
 example: 2004-08-22 17:13:04<br>
          2004-08-22 17:13<br>
          2004-08-22<br>
</small>
<input type=text size=20 name='histfr' value='$fetched{histfr}'>
 - 
<input type=text size=20 name='histto' value='$fetched{histto}'><br>
<input type=submit name='submit' value='history'>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br><br>
";
&print_filepool;
print "</body></html>";
exit;
}

sub makeoper {
#   $error="pingvin";
%attr = (
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 0
);
$dbh=DBI->connect($configs{db_source},$configs{db_user},$configs{db_passw},\%attr) or die "Can not connect to database: $DBI::errstr!\n";

#print DBI->
#die "Cannot connect to DB!" if (!defined $dbh);
 if ($fetched{submit} eq 'start' and !$fetched{savefr} )
  {$fetched{savefr}=&get_time_fromdb;
   $fetched{saveto}='';
   system "mv pool/*.txt pool/arc/";
  }
 elsif ($fetched{submit} eq 'cut' and $fetched{savefr} )
  {$fetched{saveto}=&get_time_fromdb;
   &dumptofile($fetched{savefr},$fetched{saveto});
   $fetched{savefr}=$fetched{saveto};
   $fetched{saveto}='';
  }
 elsif ($fetched{submit} eq 'stop' and $fetched{savefr} )
  {$fetched{saveto}=&get_time_fromdb;
   &dumptofile($fetched{savefr},$fetched{saveto});
   $fetched{savefr}='';
   $fetched{saveto}='';
  }
 elsif ($fetched{submit} eq 'history')
  {
   system "mv pool/*.txt pool/arc/";
   &normalize_times($fetched{histfr},$fetched{histto});
   &humanize_times($fetched{histfr},$fetched{histto});
   &dumptofile($fetched{histfr},$fetched{histto});

  }
 $dbh->disconnect or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
}

sub get_time_fromdb {
 $sth=$dbh->prepare("select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual ");
 $sth->execute();
 $row=$sth->fetchrow_arrayref;
 $sth->finish;
 return $row->[0];
}

sub dumptofile { #pass savefr,saveto
 my ($savefr,$saveto)=@_;
 $sth=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $configs{dbtable}
                     WHERE     (mess_dir='I' OR mess_dir='A' OR mess_dir='R') "
                    .($configs{nums_filter}
                       ? " and b_num in $configs{nums_filter} "
                       : ''
                     )
                    ."     and in_date>to_date(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                           and in_date<to_date(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                     ORDER BY b_num, in_date
                    ");
 $sth->execute($savefr,$saveto);
$destnum = "";
 if ($configs{nums_div})
  {open OFI,">pool/$savefr - $saveto - mark.txt";
   close OFI;
   while ($row=$sth->fetchrow_arrayref)
    {if ($row->[2] ne $destnum)
      {$destnum=$row->[2];
       open OFI,">pool/$savefr - $saveto - $destnum.txt";
      }
     $row->[3]=~s/[\r\n]/ /mg;
     print OFI join("\t",@$row),"\n";
    }
  }
 else
  {open OFI,">pool/$savefr - $saveto.txt";
   while ($row=$sth->fetchrow_arrayref)
    {print OFI join("\t",@$row),"\n";}
  }
 close OFI;
 $sth->finish;
}

sub print_filepool {
 opendir IDI,'pool/';
 foreach $afile (sort { $b cmp $a } readdir IDI)
  {if ($afile=~/txt\Z/)
   {print "<a target='_blank' href='$configs{pathtopool}/$afile'>";
    print `wc -l \'pool/$afile\'`;
    print "</a><br>\n";
   };
  };
 closedir IDI;
 print "<br><a target='_blank' href='list.cgi?arc'>ARC</a><br>\n";
}

sub parse_form { #sets %fetched=('name0'=>'content0',..)
 if ($ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}>$configs{'universal_maxinfosize_totake'}) {return 0;};
 read(STDIN,$buffer,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
 if (length($buffer)<5) {$buffer=$ENV{QUERY_STRING};};
 @pairs=split(/&/,$buffer);
 foreach $pair (@pairs)
  {local($name,$value)=split(/=/, $pair);
   $name =~tr/+/ /;
   $name =~s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
   $value =~tr/+/ /;
   $value =~s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
   $value =~s/[<>\n\r|`]/ /mg;
   if ($fetched{$name} eq '') {$fetched{$name}=$value;}
   else {$fetched{$name}.="\a$value";};
  }
 return 1;
}

sub normalize_times { #pass fr_time, to_time
 $_[0]=~s/\D+//sg;
 $_[1]=~s/\D+//sg;
 $_[0].='000000' if ($_[0]=~m/^\d{8}$/);
 $_[1].='235959' if ($_[1]=~m/^\d{8}$/);
 $_[0].='00' if ($_[0]=~m/^\d{12}$/);
 $_[1].='59' if ($_[1]=~m/^\d{12}$/);
 $_[1]='' if ($_[1]!~m/^\d{14}$/);
}

sub humanize_times { #pass fr_time, to_time
 $_[0]=substr($_[0],0,4)."-".substr($_[0],4,2)."-".substr($_[0],6,2)
       ." ".substr($_[0],8,2).":".substr($_[0],10,2).":".substr($_[0],12,2);
 $_[1]=substr($_[1],0,4)."-".substr($_[1],4,2)."-".substr($_[1],6,2)
       ." ".substr($_[1],8,2).":".substr($_[1],10,2).":".substr($_[1],12,2);
}
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );` (or `-w` and `use strict;`)!

Comment: to quote your source: `sub parse_form { #sets %fetched=('name0'=>'content0',..)`

Comment: @ysth, I know, I had seen that comment. But I just couldn't understand how it could work without declaring it first. In JavaScript, for instance, you'd get `some variable is undefined` error, not to mention, Java or C#, which won't even let you compile it. I know, I Perl is loosely typed language.

Comment: Please consider the following suggestions: Use CGI.pm to parse your form and produce the headers. Remove the HTML from your code and use a templating engine to produce the output. Stop calling subroutines with `&`. Use Time::Piece or DateTime to format your dates and times. Your code will shrink to about a quarter of the size and will be far simpler to understand. This reads like bad Perl code from 1995!

Comment: @DaveCross, it's exactly a bad Perl code from 1995. I'd take your advice but I'm anyway going to rewrite this in JSP. I need to analyze the code to grasp the whole idea.

Comment: "I'm anyway going to rewrite this in JSP" Oh, bad luck :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl is seeing that you are using a variable named `%fetched` so it just goes ahead and creates one for you.  This is behavior that is a hold over from the early days of Perl.

You should `use strict;` at the top of your file, and then declare `my %fetched;` near the top, since it is being used as a global variable.

Compare:

```
perl -e '$foo{bar}=42; print $foo{bar} . "\n";'
42

perl -e 'use strict; $foo{bar}=42; print $foo{bar} . "\n";'
Global symbol "%foo" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

[perldoc strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html)

Answer (score 4):

That's the problem you face when you don't use `use strict; use warnings;` in your program.

`fetched` is a hash which is probably containing your form data.

Also see: [Autovivification in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/autovivification)